# Output is printing twice

Tags: python

The output of this code is printing twice.

```py
print("Welcome to Band Name Generator!")
Query_1 = "What is the name of the city you grew up in ? "
input(Query_1)
Query_2 = "What is your pet's name ? "
input(Query_2)
print("Your band name could be" + input(Query_1) + input(Query_2))
```

I'm a beginner so I don't really know what to do and expect.

Comment: You are calling input() twice for each query. Call it once and save the returned result then just print that. So pet = input (Query_2) or such like.

Comment: Query_1 and Query_2 are variable names. So while printing, you should just mention just Query_1 and Query_2. (i.e) `print("Your band name could be " + Query_1 + ',' + Query_2) `

Comment: In your own words: when the code runs, in total how many times do you think the `input` function will be used? (Hint: if you use your editor's find function, how many times does it find `input` in the code?) What happens when that function is used? How many times *should* `input` run, in order for the logic to work the way you want? Each time that `input` is used, *what should happen to* the result?

Comment: Python has the neat feature where you can put the input() function anywhere, not just on a single line. By putting the input() in the final print statement, you are asking for input again. A simple trick is to count how many input() functions are. There are 4 in your case.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the `input()` function twice each for Query_1 and Query_2. You need to remove the duplicate call. Also, you need to format your result string to give your desired output because your current code prefixes every output with 'be'. See my fixes to your code:

```
print("Welcome to Band Name Generator!")
Query_1 = input("What is the name of the city you grew up in ? ")
Query_2 = input("What is your pet's name ? ")
print(f"Your band name could be {Query_1 + Query_2}")
```